# почему объект не изменяет свою позицию

Tags: python, pygame

почему при данном коде Ship не изменяет свою позицию

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

sc = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 1200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

x = 600
y = 600

K = pygame

def SpaceShip(xShip, yShip):
    ship_surf = pygame.image.load('spaceShip.png')
    ship_rect = ship_surf.get_rect(bottomright=(xShip - 32, yShip - 32))
    ship_surf = pygame.transform.scale(ship_surf, (100,100))
    sc.blit(ship_surf, ship_rect)

pygame.display.update()

while True:
    sc.fill((0,0,0))
    SpaceShip(x, y)
    
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    if keys == K.K_LEFT:
        x -= 3
    elif keys == K.K_RIGHT:
        x += 3      

    pygame.display.update()     
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы не правильно проверяете нажатие кнопок, должно быть так:

```
if keys[K.K_LEFT]:
    x -= 3
elif keys[K.K_RIGHT] :
    x+= 3
```